# Borrar un valor de un nodo

Tags: c, lista

Estoy intentando borrar un dato de mi lista pero resulta que se borra el valor siguiente del número que quiero borrar.

Por ejemplo, tengo en mi lista:

```
7 0 5 18 2
```

Quiero borrar el `0`, y que al visualizar quede:

```
7 5 18 2
```

Con el código que tengo queda así:

```
7 0 18 2
```

Se borra el siguiente valor de `0`, o sea, `5`.

Codigo:

```
printf("\n\nNumero de la lista a borrar: ");//Valor del nodo a borrar
scanf("%d",&numeroABorrar);

anterior = primero;
while ((anterior->dato != numeroABorrar) && (anterior != NULL))
{
    anterior = anterior->siguiente;
}       

if (anterior != NULL)
{   
    aux = anterior->siguiente;  
    anterior->siguiente = aux->siguiente;
    free(aux);      
}
```

Comment: Hola, ¿qué problema estás teniendo?, ¿no compila?, ¿te sale algún error?

Comment: Yo tengo mis nodos con sus valores en mi lista que son el 7-0-5-18-2 y quiero borrar el 0, pues me borra el 5. Osea el valor siguiente

Comment: Ah, ya veo. No me di cuenta de esa parte en tu pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que al haber una coincidencia la variable que contiene el valor a borrar es *anterior* pero la reasignacion que tu haces es que el **siguiente de *anterior***(el que quieres borrar) sea el **siguiente del siguiente del que quieres borrar**, por lo que **se pierde la referencia al siguiente del que deseas borrar**. Digamos que te estas pasando por un valor. Espero que con el siguiente ejemplo quede mas claro.

Aplicándolo a la lista:

En anterior esta el 0

En aux esta el 5

El siguiente del 0(de anterior) ahora es el 18, ya se perdió la referencia al 5

Para corregir esto necesitas una referencia al antecesor del valor que quieres borrar(7) y al siguiente de ese valor asignar el siguiente del que quieres borrar(cambiar la referencia al 0 por la referencia al 5):

```
printf("\n\nNumero de la lista a borrar: ");//Valor del nodo a borrar
scanf("%d",&numeroABorrar);

actual = primero;
while ((actual->dato != numeroABorrar) && (actual != NULL))
{   
    anterior = actual;
    actual = actual->siguiente;
}       

if (actual != NULL)
{   
    //codigo que verifica el caso de que el elemento a borrar
    //sea el primero
    if(actual == primero){
        primero = primero->siguiente;
    }
    else{
        anterior->siguiente = actual->siguiente;
    }                 
}
```

Nota que ya no es necesaria la variable aux y que antes de pasar al siguiente del actual en el ciclo while guardo una referencia a el en *anterior* para poder cambiar su 
*siguiente*

Comment: Muchas gracias, buena explicación me he enterado, pero necesito practicar mas. Saludos

Comment: Hay un pequeño problema, ahora si borra correctamente el valor que desees borrar, pero al intentar borrar el primer valor de la lista, osea el 7, salta que el programa dejo de funcionar

Comment: Ah, cierto. Lo que pasa es que al encontrar la coincidencia en el primer valor nunca entra al while y anterior no esta inicializado.

Comment: Debe verificarse el caso de que el elemento a eliminar sea el primero, de ser así se cambia primero por su siguiente